# Why is a / at the end of my URLs giving me a 500 error and why is .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am running a simple HTML site, with a .htaccess edit. I have several issues.

If I don't put https then - www.example.com/apply will redirect to https www.xyz.com/apply.html - I understand I have the https redirect on. However, I also have it so .html is removed.

https www.xyz.com/apply will load fine

https www.xyz.com/apply/ will give a 500 error because there is a / at the end

.htaccess code is as follows

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Any ideas? I wrote the code from memory so hopefully I'm not missing something.

Comment: You'll need to include a case where a trailing `/` will be rewritten as well. `(/|)`

Comment: You should probably redirect requests with paths ending with `/` to without, for SEO.  https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you consider all wrong requests without `/` then you handle them like that , so you should check first whether a wrong request has `/` or not , then remove it internally , if you want a file look like directory,then handle it by the next rules , priority will be for `html` then to `php` so , your rules should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#as per your comment that all css files under /css directory i added the
#following rules

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    \.css$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/css/(.*)$    /css/$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^    %1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php  [L,QSA]
```

**NOTE:** Clear browser cache the test .

**Update:**

If you want `CSS` files work while you adding `/` to files , there is a workaround , for example you put all `CSS` files in `cssfolder` directory , so when the request come to either html or php files without trailing slash , css will load normally like /cssfolder/file.css , but with trailing slash the path will be different /file/cssfolder/file.css  , you could add rule to remove any request end with `css` that has any thing before `cssfolder` directory .

Like that :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/cssfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    \.css$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/cssfolder/(.*)$    /cssfolder/$2 [L]
```

These rules above should be after `RewriteEngine On` at you rules above.

Comment: I tried this. However, I had the following issues;

1) the home page loaded with .index.html every time

2) when I added a / at the end of the url it would get it to load without any css

Comment: @James this line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$ should be like this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$ to exclude site.com/ from rule get updated code

Comment: @James clear browser cache the test it , it will solve CSS peoblem as well because I removed wrong requests trailing slash which cause this problem

Comment: @James see my Update notes

Comment: thanks for clarification. index.html portion didn't load, as you said. However, the CSS is still causing an issue. It will not load. It's strange because I have other links that I write like example-page and it works fine, or even /example-page

Comment: @James for CSS is there any issue with pages with out trailing slash?

Comment: @James you should know all css directories then add them in one rule , I could modify the example to cover your need

Comment: there are no issues without trailing slash. My css is simple it's in /css folder

Comment: @James ok , then if the name of CSS folder is css , use the last rule just replace cssfolder with the name of your css files folder and put it first after RewriteEngine On then clear browser cache and test it

Comment: @James i made and update , copy all rules then clear browser cache and test

Comment: thank you very much, I also realized that if I want a trailing slash to come after the link name then in the dev side I would also have to put a slash at the start of all files on the server, to ensure css, js etc load properly. js/nav.js wouldn't work. However, /js/nav.js works now. Thank you again.